# Change the script when running remotely by Delphi FDScript

Tags: sql, delphi

This line changes when I run a script remotely on another server.
This line in the script

`{ D '1970-01-01' }`

changes to

`CONVERT(DATETIME, '''1970-01-01'' ', 20)`

Why does this happen?

Comment: Firedac pre-processes query text. One thing it does it convert escape sequence to the target database (or what it thinks is the target). One example of that is constant substitution which is what you are seeing. See: [Preprocessing Command Text (FireDAC)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Escape_Sequences)

Answer (score 1):

The Problem Solved with set this property

`FDScript1.ResourceOptions.EscapeExpand := false;`